# Is it possible to add title/custom component above ag-grid nested table?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using `ag-grid` (in an `Angular` project) to render a nested table and I want to add a title and a button on top of the child table. I could not find anything in `ag-grid` documentation.

I am fine with having a separate custom component to be rendered there. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Any workaround or suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is you can add on ag-grid
`[detailCellRenderer]="detailCellRenderer"`

In ts file you can define your own component & map with detailCellRenderer

```
public detailCellRenderer = PanelViewComponent;
```

Code for Custom compoenet

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel-view',
  templateUrl: './panel-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-view.component.scss'],
})
export class PanelViewComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
public params!: ICellRendererParams;
agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }
}
```

in HTML you can define your child grid and tables & header & buttons anything you want.

Comment: For future readers, this will come handy: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail-custom-detail/